# Reverse self referencing foreign key in Django

Tags: python, database, django, self-referencing-table

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm a bit of a Django newbie and can't find the answer.

I have an Order model with a self-referencing field:

```
source = models.ForeignKey(
    'self',
    help_text = "[redacted]",
    verbose_name = "Source Order",
    blank = True,
    null = True,
)
```

While this works fine if I have an Order and I want to know its source, I also need to get a list of an Order's "children" - that is, a list of Orders for which this Order is the source. Does this need to be done through `filter()`s or is there a nice, Django-y way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an Order object, you can use the [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
child_orders = my_order.order_set.all()
```

You may want to give the `source` field a more descriptive `related_name` value which would be used in place of `order_set` above.

Comment: That did it, and it sure sounds like a Right Answer(tm) too. Thank you!